# Fix multiple inheritance with generic base classes

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, python-typing

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Any

R = TypeVar('R')
X = TypeVar('X')

class SizedIterator(Generic[X]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

class TfmIterator(Generic[R],  SizedIterator):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
```

The above is a much simplified version of the code in https://github.com/autorope/donkeycar/blob/dev/donkeycar/pipeline/sequence.py.

Apparently that code worked fine in Python 3.6 and/or 3.7. However, it gives the following error when I try to run it in Python 3.9:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Shared/Personal/mycar/simple1.py", line 10, in <module>
    class TfmIterator(Generic[R],  SizedIterator):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Generic, SizedIterator
```

My question is what can I do to keep the same type hints without running into the MRO error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Any

R = TypeVar('R')
X = TypeVar('X')


class SizedIterator(Generic[X]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass


class NewIterator(Generic[R]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass


class TfmIterator(NewIterator, SizedIterator):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for both the simplified example and the original code.

Answer (score 4):

Factoring out an additional base class should not be necessary. The key rules are:

- `Generic` must always be the *last* base class.
- When doing diamond inheritance in general, you may have to explicitly write much of the MRO as immediate parents even if they are already indirect parents. Printing out the MROs of the parents may help you figure out what you need to write to get the MRO you want.
- if the ultimately-derived class should *not* accept generic parameters and you require your rightmost base to be something that does not derive from `Generic`, then you will have to add a "bogus" base class that is actually an alias for `Generic[T]` but uses `if TYPE_CHECKING` to replace itself with an empty class for type analyzers.